# Which is less performant? defining and calling a default blank function vs type checking if the function exists before calling it

Tags: javascript, performance

Which is more performant? I prefer the first one as it's more pleasing to read vs the second one. Even if it's a minuscule amount of performance gain which is better?

```
function(callback = () => {}) {
    callback();
}
```

vs:

```
function(callback) {
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback()
    }
}
```

Comment: Both are executed nearby four billion times per second, why should you care?

Comment: That depends where this code is executed. If it's in a tied high-rate animation for instance, the first one *could* define a new function every time which would then make the Garbarge Collector have to kick in, eating a bit of processor time. In almost any other case that just shouldn't matter. As always for perfs questions, measure yourself in real conditions.